# close() never close connections in pymongo?

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

I use MongoDB and I connect to it through pymongo. Here's my code:

```
>>> import pymongo
>>> con=pymongo.Connection('localhost',27017)
>>> con.database_names()
['local', 'bookdb']
>>> con.close()
>>> con.database_names()
['local', 'bookdb']
```

I use `con.close()` to disconnect to the MongoDB, but after that, I can still use  `con.database_names()`  to see the list of the databases. Why? it never disconnect to the MongoDB server. Why the `close()` not work?

Answer (score 14):

Just read the docs, faster and more detailed.

> If this instance is used again it will be automatically re-opened.

[Link to docs](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/mongo_client.html#pymongo.mongo_client.MongoClient.close)

Comment: Yep, I notice that. But I only use close() once! How could that be?

Comment: The lib maintains a connection pool.

Comment: I'm new to mongodb, what does the connection pool use for? meaning we couldn't disconnect to the mongodb?

Comment: They are closed if you call close.

Comment: You mean I have already closed the connection, but when I call the method **database_names()** it's reopened?

Comment: @socket A little late, but for the sake of posterity, yup