# PyMongo on the Flask

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, config, pymongo

I'm curious if this is right working.

In case of using *MySQL*, both connecting and closing are done per one request.

> 1st request: connect, close
>   2nd request: connect, close
>   3rd request: connect, close
>   4th request: connect, close
>   5th request: connect, close

every requests bring both connect and close
This is how I manage MySQL connection and think many of other developer do like this.

**BUT..**

In case of using *mongodb with PyMongo module*, it works not like above.

> 1st request: connect
>   2nd request: connect
>   3rd request: (use connection of 1st or 2nd) <= Do not connect but use previous connection
>   4th request: (use connection of 1st or 2nd) <= same
>   5th request: (use connection of 1st or 2nd) <= same

Does this keep the connection in app.config and use on after request?
I feel How it works is very difficult from managing connection of MySQL.
Is this normal working?
Doesn't it need to close the connection after using?

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_pymongo import PyMongo
app = Flask(__name__)

app.config['MONGO_HOST'] = '127.0.0.1'
app.config['MONGO_PORT'] = 27017
app.config['MONGO_DBNAME'] = 'test'
mongo = PyMongo(app, config_prefix='MONGO')

@app.route('/')
def test():
    mongo.db.user.insert({'name':'test'})
    return 'test'

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

Thank you for read.

Comment: I think this is answer you are looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/a/20613627/5802335

Comment: How are you getting the information about connections opening and closing? I'm curious to know

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to close PyMongo connections. Leave them open so that PyMongo's connection pooling gives you the most efficient performance:

https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/faq.html#how-does-connection-pooling-work-in-pymongo

Your code, above, is correct. Create one "PyMongo" instance and reuse it throughout your application.

Comment: Thank you very much! I am happy for me doing right :)